How to calculate optimal window size from input series data for detecting swing highs/lows?
I'm trying to automate detection of swing highs/lows for crypto trading.
Since I want my function swing_levels(price_data) to be agnostic and work for any timeframe, and crypto tokens, therefore it should derive all needed parameters from input OHLCV data without requiring me to tune them manually.
Going to use argrelextrema within my swing_levels(price_data) to detect swings. argrelextrema has order(window) parameter. How to calculate an optimal window size based on provided input OHLCV price data?

Optimal by what criteria? What is OHLCV? What knowledge of crypto tokens should we understand?

@btilly OHLCV stands for open, high, low, close, volume price data. So I'm open to suggestions regarding optimal window rather than using static one.

You still need to specify what you mean by an optimal window size.  Also you should tell us what a swing high and a swing low is.  Do you care about performance?  If you do not care about performance, then I would guess that the 'optimal' window size would be the entire range of available data - why throw any away?  This question is far too vague for anyone to give you a sensible answer.

Suggestion: Write some code that tries different window sizes on historical data and calculates the value of  an objective function that captures what you mean by 'optimal'.  Select the window size that gives the best value of your objective function.  If you hit a snag writing that code, THEN you will have a question suitable for this site.

@ravenspoint by optimal I mean a way to determine window size dynamically from data to detect actionable local minima/maxima (support/resistance levels). The simple way is min/max of the range but this is obviously way less than I need. On other side, too many points will make noisy levels with low probability to works as support/resistance levels.

"The simple way is min/max of the range"  This suggest you are not looking for a window in t ( the independent variable ) but in y ( the dependent ).  You really must clarify your question!!!!

@ravenspoint the key is argrelextrema function which has window argument. I want to pass dynamic window argument based on input price data, so it's calculated rather than using static value e.g. 5. The question is whether it's feasible to calculate it dynamically e.g. using volatility, statistics and etc. I don't know this domain enough, that's why I'm asking here.

looks like it's more about trading than programming, doesn't it?

@ravenspoint I understand that you are out of the trading context, let others help us.

for info, scipy has other interresting functions like find_peaks, peak_prominences, peak_widths, ...
